# Does NSKeyedArchiver overwrite the previous archive value?

Tags: ios, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am using the following to do IOS App data backup

- **NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject()**
- **NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile()**

Based on the Apple documentation here -

- [iOS Developer Library - iOS Apps (Swift) - Persist Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson10.html)

I was curious here with a potentially silly question - does the previous archive get deleted each time you make a new save?

**Question**

- When calling NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject() does the new archive overwrite the previous archive value?
- If it doesn't overwrite the old value do you need to delete the old value?

Here is a useful reference on deleting NSKeyedArchiver values

- [stack overflow - Deleting files archived with NSCoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023018/deleting-files-archived-with-nscoding)

Comment: Here is a link saying the answer is YES. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993553/does-nskeyedarchiver-overwrite-the-entire-file-every-time-you-archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NSKeyedArchiver** is not responsible to **overwrite** the previous object. It just convert *youObject* to *NSData* and vice versa. Because, 'Custom Object' can't be save to *NSUserDefaults*.

additionay, to overrite data you should do this.i.e

```
 [userDefaults setObject:data forKey:identifier];
 [userDefaults synchronize];
```

Remove data:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:identifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: hmmm. do we need to delete the old value if it isn't overwritten?